# OpenGL - Is there an easier way to fill window with a texture, instead using VBO,etc?

Tags: opengl

My OpenGL window is drawn like this:

```
glClearColor(0.3f, 0.4f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

I want to use a texture to fill up the window.

**Is there an easier way to do that, instead of creating another VBO, EBO besides the one I'm already using for my triangles?**

Since there is the glClearColor that fills the background..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The most direct and generally most efficient way to draw a texture to the window is by using `glBlitFramebuffer()`.

To use this, you need to create an FBO, and attach your texture `texId` to it:

```
GLuint fboId = 0;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &fboId);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, fboId);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
                       GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId, 0);
```

Note that the code above bound `GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER`, since we want to use this as the source of the blit.

Then, to copy the content:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);  // if not already bound
glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, width, height, 0, 0, width, height,
                  GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_NEAREST);
```

This is for the case where texture and window have the same size. Otherwise, you can specify different sizes in the first 8 arguments, and may want to use `GL_LINEAR` for the last parameter.

Using `glBlitFramebuffer()` has a few advantages over drawing a window sized textured quad:

1. It needs fewer API calls.
2. You don't need to write a shader for the copy operation.
3. You don't need to bind a different shader program, which can reduce overhead.
4. The driver may have a more optimized code path for the operation, compared to using an app provided shader and draw call.
5. Many GPUs have dedicated units for blitting data, which can be more efficient than the programmable shader units. They can also potentially run in parallel to the general purpose programmable part of the GPU, allowing the copy to be executed in parallel with rendering. If that applies, the performance gain can be very substantial.

Answer (score 6):

There are already some answers to this question, but I want to add some more alternatives, for completeness:

**1. attributeless rendering**

With modern GL, you can render completely without vertex attributes. You can put the 4 2d coordiantes of the full screen rect directly as a const array into the vertex shader and access  them via `gl_VertexID`:

```
// VERTEX SHADER
#version 150 core
out vec2 v_tex;

const vec2 pos[4]=vec2[4](vec2(-1.0, 1.0),
                          vec2(-1.0,-1.0),
                          vec2( 1.0, 1.0),
                          vec2( 1.0,-1.0));

void main()
{
    v_tex=0.5*pos[gl_VertexID] + vec2(0.5);
    gl_Position=vec4(pos[gl_VertexID], 0.0, 1.0)
}

// FRAGMENT SHADER
#version 150 core
in vec2 v_tex;
uniform sampler2D texSampler;
out vec4 color;
void main()"
{
    color=texture(texSampler, v_tex);
}
```

If your texture exactly matches the resolution of your viewport (so you are not scaling the texture at all), you can completely remove the `v_tex` varying and use `color=texelFetch(texSampler, ivec2(gl_FragCoord.xy))` in the FS, as @datenwolf suggested in his comment.

In any case, you still need some VAO bound, even if no attributes are enabled in it. So this method requires you to do the following *once* during intialization:

- Create and compile the shaders and link them to the program
- Create a new VAO name by a `glGenVertexArrays()` call

And for drawing, you have to:

- Bind the texture you want to draw
- Use the program
- Bind the (still empty) VAO
- `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4)`

You might also be able to simply re-use the currently bound VAO. As the shader does not access any attributes, it does not matter what data your VBOs provide, and which attributes are enabled currently.

This method requires you to switch the shader, which isn't exactly cheap either, so it might be better to just switch the buffer bindigs and keep the current shader.. But you might need to switch the shader anyway.

**2. nvidia-specifc extension**

NVidia provides a specific extension for the task of drawing a texture to the screen: [NV_draw_texture](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/NV/draw_texture.txt). This introduces the `glDrawTextureNV()` function which allows drawing a texture *without* setting changing anything on the GL state. Quoting from the overview section of the extension spec:

> While this functionality can be obtained in unextended OpenGL by drawing a
>       rectangle and using a fragment shader to do a texture lookup,
>       `DrawTextureNV()` is likely to have better power efficiency on
>       implementations supporting this extension.  Additionally, **use of this
>       extension frees the application developer from having to set up
>       specialized shaders, transformation matrices, vertex attributes, and
>       various other state in order to render the rectangle**.

The drawback of this method is of course that it is nvidia-specific, so it is probably of less practical use in a general GL application.

Answer (score 3):

In one word: No.

Well in legacy OpenGL there'd be `glDrawPixels` but this function never was very well supported and dead slow on most implementation. You better forget that I told you about it. Also it's been removed from modern OpenGL and never existed in OpenGL-ES.

Comment: Also, in modern GL there is `glBlitFramebuffer`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: `glBlitFramebuffer` will only blit from one framebuffer (FBO or main window buffer) to another framebuffer. You can't blit arbitrary images. Yes, in theory you can attach a texture as a color attachment of an FBO and blit from that. But why would you do that (jump through so many hoops), if you can just as well have a `gl_FragColor = texelFetch(gl_FragCoord)` fragment shader (add a viewport offset uniform if you want to freely move around the picture in the window.

Answer (score 1):

You can render your texture to a fullscreen quad using an ortographic projection:

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);

// Set up ortographic projection
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0, width, 0, height, -1, 1);

// Render a quad
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(0,0); glVertex2f(0,0);
glTexCoord2f(0,1); glVertex2f(0,width);
glTexCoord2f(1,1); glVertex2f(height, width);
glTexCoord2f(1,0); glVertex2f(height,0);
glEnd();

// Reset Projection Matrix
glPopMatrix();
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
```

Render this into your framebuffer instead of glClearColor.